# removing a section of text based upon an offset of two string

Tags: string, sed, awk

I have a need to removed a bunch of lines in a text file that are an offset from two unique strings.

**Input**

```
startdoc
  apple
  apple
  start of section
    WELCOME
    this bunch of fruit 
    tastes like chicken
  end of section
  start of section
    chapter1
    I have all the orange 
    in the world
  end of section
endoc
```

**Output**

```
startdoc
  apple
  apple
  start of section
    WELCOME
    this bunch of fruit 
    tastes like chicken
  end of section
endoc
```

From the above example, the first line to delete is line 9 to line 13. Essentially, removing the first section.

I have tried with sed using the line number specifiers but the line number will changes for different files.

Ideally, if I specify to sed to start deleting from the line just before "chapter1" and sed to stop deleting at the line just before "enddoc". the start and end points is an offset of -1 lines. Any ideas how I can do this via sed?

Comment: I don't understand it. What is the condition to remove the first section based in the second one?

Comment: @Birei, I made a mistake with the example, corrected. I want to keep the first section, and get rid of all subsequent sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can handle this problem easier:

```
awk '
    /start of section/ { flag++ } 
    /start of section/,/end of section/ { 
        if ( flag == 1 ) { 
            print 
        } 
        next 
    } 
    { print }
' infile
```

It increments a flag each time it finds a line that matches `start of section` and for each section checks this flag. In the beginning of second and following sections the `flag` variable will have a value larger than one and will skip them without printing.

It yields:

```
startdoc
  apple
  apple
  start of section
    WELCOME
    this bunch of fruit 
    tastes like chicken
  end of section
endoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
sed -n "1,/end of section/ p;$ p" file
```

This outputs everything up to the end of the first section and then just the last line after that.